# Image Orientation from

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the orientation of a picture that you took with the camera?

I am using the method below to recover orientations of images that are in my gallery, but if I take pictures with the camera it does not work.

```
   public static int getImageOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    int orientation = -1;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() == 1) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "does not work"?

Comment: It works when I use it with images from gallery and an image that I shot from camera now dont work, the cursor(from contentRsolver) is null. But the answer bellow works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the orientation of image from below code:

```
try {
    context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    }

    Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
    Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here first you have to save the captured image on sd card and then fetch the image Uri from the path where the image is saved. Then pass that Uri as imageUri in the posted code.