# android image upload rotates only images in camera folder

Tags: android, image, http, base64, gallery

I have an application which lets the user select an image, resizes that image using bitmaps, then converts this image into base64 and uploads it to a PHP script where its then decoded and saved to a file.

The problem is that when the user selects a image which is stored in the camera folder of the gallery it rotates it by 90 degrees anticlockwise. If you select a photo in any other folder, the result is as expected (not rotated).

Has anyone had any experience with either bitmaps, base64 or sending over HTTP whereby it rotates images?? i really have no idea what it could be.

I can supply source code if required.

Comment: You may find a solution on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview/

Comment: You may refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18577278/1952459). If you require any help with how to implement, let me know.